# How to disable inline function definition in zsh

Tags: zsh

Zsh is a very powerful shell, but once in a while I get surprised as it goes one step too far.

Recently I've had one of these surprisingly puzzling moments after typing the following commands (adapted for simplicity and clarity):

```
% echo "nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand"
nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand

% echo nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand

% echo "nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand"
echo:3: command not found: nosuchcommand

% echo I used to like this
echo:4: command not found: nosuchcommand
```

It took me a while to understand what was going on and that this was specific to zsh and not the command I was trying to execute. At line 2 I've created some sort of inline function that got assigned to "echo". At least that's the only explanation that makes sense in the light of the output of lines 3 and 4.

As a comparison, in bash things make a little bit more sense:

```
% echo "nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand"
nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand

% echo nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

% echo "nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand"
nosuchfunction() nosuchcommand

% echo I used to like this
I used to like this
```

At this point I'm also not sure if this is supposed to be a feature or a bug, but I would simply like to disable this behavior.

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you created two functions, `echo` and `nosuchfunction`, both executing `nosuchcommand`.

`zsh` allows not only 'inline function definition' (as in: you do not need to use braces or parenthis if your function contains only one command), but also allows for multiple names given to the same function. From `zshmisc(1)`:

```
function word ... [ () ] [ term ] { list }
word ... () [ term ] { list }
word ... () [ term ] command
     where term is one or more newline or ;.  Define a function which is
     referenced by any one of word.  Normally, only one word is provided;   
     multiple  words  are  usually  only useful for setting traps.  The 
     body of the function is the list between the { and }.  See the
     section `Functions'.
```

This issue can be somewhat avoided by disabling the `MULTI_FUNC_DEF` option (`unsetopt multifuncdef`), which allows the definition of multiple functions without the `function` keyword. As noted in the manpage `zshoptions(1)` for `MULTI_FUNC_DEF`:

> Multiple function  definitions  are  not  often used and can cause obscure errors.

Aside from that it is best to remember that parenthesis are syntactic elements, in `zsh` as well as in `bash`, and if you do not want to use them as such you have to quote them. (It is not as if the second line did work in `bash`, so just disabling 'inline definitions' would not solve anything anyway.)